# Reference Shared Object AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to reference a shared object (one that saves data), but whenever I try to, I get a crash.

This code works fine:

```
var var1:Object = { value:1 };
var varRef:Object = var1;

if(var1.value == 1) {
    varRef.value = 50;
}

trace(varRef.value); // outputs 50;
trace(var1.value); // outputs 50;
```

But when I try to use shared objects, it doesn't work.

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;
var iapso:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("purchases");
var varRef:Object = iapso.data.testing;

varRef = 90
trace ("The shared value is " + iapso.data.testing);
trace ("This should mirror it" + varRef);
```

If you're able to figure out the issue, please post a fixed version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must come from a programming background where pointers can be dereferenced.

In this case, `varRef` is not `varRef = &iapso`.  Setting its value does not change the value of `iapso.data.testing`;

Initially, you set `varRef` as a pointer to `iapso.data.testing`:

```
var varRef:Object = iapso.data.testing;
```

Then, you immediately change it to a constant value object literal `90`:

```
varRef = 90;
```

This does not set the value of `testing` to 90 - this changes the value of `varRef`.

You could set `varRef` to `iapso.data`, then set `testing` as in:

```
var varRef:Object = iapso.data;
varRef.testing = 90;
```

Then, the following would produced expected results:

```
trace(iapso.data.testing); // 90
trace(varRef.testing); // 90
```

Comment: Jason Sturges you did it again! Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

setting varRef will not update the value in iapso.data - numbers are copied, not referenced.

```
var bar:Object = { data:1 };
var foo:Object = bar.data;

trace(foo); //"1"
bar.data = 2;
trace(foo); //"1"
```

If you really want to use a reference, use `data` instead, eg:

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;
var iapso:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("purchases");
var varRef:Object = iapso.data;

varRef.testing = 90
trace ("The shared value is " + iapso.data.testing);
trace ("This should mirror it" + varRef.testing);
```